# Is it normal to cache a script tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a partial like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  -- javascript code here --
</script>
```

I was trying to use "Fragment Caching":

```
<% cache "script_code" do %>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    -- javascript code here --
   </script>
<% end %>
```

Is it common to use "Fragment Caching" like this?

Answer (score 1):

I would say best practice is to separate your script code in to a separate .js file and then the file itself would be served as a static asset and always from cache. If you are generating dynamic javascript based on some code, this could be acceptable as long as the point of the cache is not to serve the js itself but the calculation that makes that js dynamic such as db query.